# Why is my insertion sort not liking duplicate integers?

Tags: c, insertion-sort

When I feed my sort code with a list of integers that has duplicates, the code doesn't function properly. My guess is that for each duplicate integer, the number of other integers in the list that are smaller than it are the same for every duplicate. Thus, the position for each duplicate is the same in the new array (`d[10]`). Here's what the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, j, k;
  int c[10];
  int d[10];

  printf("enter 10 integers each separated by a space: ");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &c[i]);
    }

  printf("before insertion: ");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) // sort loop begins here
    {
      k = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
          if (c[j] < c[i])
            {
              k = k + 1; // count number of times a smaller number is found
            }
        }
      d[k] = c[i]; // use the number k as the position in the new array
    }

  printf("after insertion: ");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      printf("%d ", d[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be prudent to show your input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Usually insertion sort doesn't work by counting the number of smaller integers...

Comment: This isn't really insertion sort. You aren't performing insertions at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is not insertion sort, the code you wrote has space complexity O(n) which is not good as far as sorting techniques are concerned and on cost of space its time complexity in all cases will be O(n^2) which is even more worst, so don't use such sorting algo.

You can search google or youtube for insertion sort.

## Why your code is creating problem?

Ans:-
Your code is placing the required element on the exact position as calculated by k. But in case you enter some duplicate elements then what happens is, the first position of duplicate elements gets encountered again and again, so your code is not actually placing the elements for the next duplicates element and at that place you get a garbage value.

## How to solve this?

Okay, so you need to change your algorithm such that, it considers all the positions and you should not place elements for two same values of k.
There are many ways to do that, one way I can suggest you is  hashing (I guess its not the best way to solve this) which is also sometimes called as pointer technique by array (you can browse for this if you don't know) you just take an array of size n, initialize it to zero and then you can count the number of time k you encounter by `array[k]++`

Hope this makes the problem clear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't insertion sort. It's similar to cycle sort, which minimizes the number of writes to d[]. I added a duplicate check using a third array e[] to indicate if a location has been written to or not. Code to test 10^8 cases. Changes noted with comments.

```
int main()
{
int c[10] = {0};                
int d[10];
int e[10];                                      // for duplicate check
int i, j, k, n;

    for(n = 0; n < 100000000; n++){             // test 10^8 cases
        k = n;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            c[i] = k%10;
            k /= 10;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){                // clear e (nothing written)
            e[i] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            k = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                if (c[j] < c[i]){
                    k = k + 1;
                }
            }
            while(e[k] != 0 && d[k] == c[i]){  // duplicate check
                k = k + 1;
            }
            d[k] = c[i];
            e[k] = 1;                          // mark index as written
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(d[i] > d[i+1]){
                printf("fail\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```